# Poisson Process in 3D?

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I'm currently working out of [Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis by John Rice](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534399428) and ran into the following problem from Chapter 2 that I have no idea on how to solve.

Ch. 2 #43

> Find the probability density for the distance from an event to its nearest neighbor for a Poisson process in three-dimensional space.

After googling around a bit I found a solution with very little explanation [here](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/39855-Poisson-process-in-3D), but I'm not sure where the use of a sphere comes from. Any help solving this problem or understanding the linked to solution would be appreciated (ie more explanation about the use of the volume of a sphere formula)

Comment: $P(D_x>t)=P(N(B(x,t))=0)=e^{-\lambda\cdot volume(B(x,t))}$. where $D_x$ is distance in question (from $x$), $N$ is Poisson count and $B(x,t)$ is ball of radius $t$ centered at $x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a moment, consider not the 3D case, but the 2D. Let $d$ be the distance between a particular point and the nearest neighbor. Notice that
$$\{d >x\}\iff \{\text{No points in the disk of radius $x$}\}$$
The sphere (ball) is the analogous case in 3D.

You are told that you have a Poisson process, and so $N(A)$ is a homogeneous Poisson process of intensity $\lambda >0$, and
$$P(N(A) = k) = e^{-\lambda|A|}\frac{(\lambda|A|)^k}{k!},$$
            for $k = 0,1,\dotsc$, where $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^3$.
In this case $A$ is a sphere, so $|A|$ denotes the volume of the sphere.

Because of spatial homogeneity, it doesn't matter where the point is in $\mathbb R^3$, and you can just consider the origin. Thus, 
if $D$ is the distance of the nearest neighbor in $\mathbb R^3$, then
\begin{align*}
F_D(x) &= P(D <x)\\
&= 1-P(D> x)\\
&= 1-P(N(A) = 0)\\
&=1- \exp\left\{-\lambda\cdot \frac{4}{3}\pi x^3\right\}
\frac{(\lambda(4/3)\pi x^3)^0}{0!}\\
&= 1- \exp\left\{-\lambda\cdot \frac{4}{3}\pi x^3\right\},
\end{align*}
where I assume the Poisson process has intensity $\lambda >0$.

Comment: Thanks! I can see now how the sphere is being used

Comment: @Math_Illiterate No, problem. I forgot to mention, you can extend this to $\mathbb R^n$. In $\mathbb R$, $|A|$ is usually the familiar length of time, and in $\mathbb R^2$, $|A|$ is for example the area of the circle.