# A square contains many random points. From each point, a disc grows until it hits the nearest neighboring point. What is the total area of the discs?

Tags: geometry, expected-value, circles, intuition, poisson-process

A unit square lamina contains $n$ independent uniformly random points. Each point is the centre of a disc whose perimeter touches the nearest neighboring point. Here is an example with $n=20$.

[image]

In this example, the total area of the discs (i.e. the sum of areas of the discs, not the area of the union of the discs) is approximately $1.0105$.

> What does the total area of the discs approach, as $n\to\infty$ ?

The answer is $1$, i.e. the area of the square itself. I give a non-intuitive proof below. But since this result is quite elegant, *I am looking for an intuitive explanation.*

### My non-intuitive proof

As $n\to\infty$, the points approach a 2D Poisson process with intensity $n$. For a chosen point, let $x$ be the distance to its nearest neighbor, which has [density function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1429850/398708)

$$f(x)=2n\pi xe^{-n\pi x^2}$$

So the total area of the discs approaches

$$n\int_0^\infty \pi x^2 f(x)\mathrm dx=1$$

by integration by parts twice.

### Remarks

The shape of the lamina (e.g. square) does not matter, since we are taking $n\to\infty$.

The answer is the same in one, two or three dimensions. (In one dimension, the nearest neighbor distance density function is $f(x)=2ne^{-2nx}$. In [three dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1597689/398708), it is $f(x)=4n\pi x^2e^{-\frac{4n\pi}{3}x^3}$.)

This question was inspired by a related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4850495/398708), "A square contains many random points. From each point, a disc grows until it hits another disc. What proportion of the square is covered by the discs?".

Comment: Does this depend on the dimension?  Does it hold in one dimension?  In three?

Comment: @MichaelLugo I have editted to address your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine adding an $(n+1)$-th point. For each of the $n$ existing points, the probability that the new point becomes the existing point’s nearest neighbour is $\frac1n$. Thus by linearity of expectation the expected number of points whose nearest neighbour the new point becomes is $1$. The disks mark the area where a new point would become the disc centre’s nearest neighbour. Thus, the sum of the disc areas inside the square is the integral over all points $x$ (and thus the expectation) of the number of points whose nearest neighbour $x$ would become if it were added as a new point. By the above, the expected value of this sum averaged over all configurations of the $n$ points is $1$. Since parts of the areas lie outside the square, their total area is expected to be slightly larger than $1$, but with $n\to\infty$ the proportion of the disc areas that lie outside the square goes to zero.